# Indirect Narration Style

Tags: style

Does the indirect narration style (as in: 'Surely she was going to ask him out tomorrow.')  directly fall into the classification of Narration?

Comment: Vote to close. Why do we keep getting all the run off from English.SE? This doesn't belong here, I don't think. =|

Comment: @Ralph Isn't it asking about a style of writing?

Comment: Actually, I think it might be us. I just did a Google search of "indirect narration style" and it does appear to have something to do with point of view. I'm not sure what is being asked here, though. Maybe someone will answer and educate us all. ;)

Comment: @kitukwfyer seems to be more of a grammar question than a style question. Defining "narration" isn't really style.

Comment: I'm a bit confused by this one, too.  Too many unfamiliar words.  Seems like indirect narration is pretty much what I'd call 'close third POV', but then I'm not sure what's meant by the 'classification of Narration' part.  Is it -- I don't know -- are we being asked if we would classify the example phrase as dialogue or as narration?  It does seem to be in a bit of a grey area between the two.  But I don't know why anyone would NEED to classify things in one camp or the other...

Comment: @Ralph I'm also pretty sure defining "narration" isn't part of grammar, either...Still the question's kind of hard to understand. Hopefully, C_P will be able to clarify what they're asking for.

Comment: It was pretty clear to me that this is about writing...

Comment: What's "the classification of narration"? Is this a taxonomy question? If so, some more detail on what taxonomy we're meant to be discussing is really rather necessary.

Comment: @Ralph: I apologize if you get too much run off for your tastes, but let me assure you that you most certainly don't get *all* of it. For every post that gets migrated here, several potential candidates get killed with fire.

Answer (score 4):

If by indirect narration you mean indirect speech, yes, I believe it is a style of third person narration. e.g. He said he would of course help. You also get free indirect speech, which is a combination of both third and first person narration by dropping the "he said" e.g. He would of course help. See here for more: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_indirect_speech

Answer (score 1):

Technically it's still the narrator (author) saying what the character may or may not be thinking so I would say yes.

In narrated films, the narrator might add their own thoughts about events here and there like this and it would fall under "narration".